# Multiple dataTable not responsive with IE8

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am facing performance issues while using multiple option with IE8(unfortunately  IE8 is the official browser in my project ):

I follow the primeface example one by one but still the user experience with IE is very poor meaning the selection is very slow , I also notice that the hover functionality is not working on both chrome and IE but I can live with that.

The interesting part is that the ShowCase example which use 4.0 (I am using 3.4) is working very nice via IE8 (maybe due to a smaller list ?).

```
<p:dataTable id="tmpCoreTable"
             var="acq"
             value="#{report.dataModel}"
             selection="#{report.selected}"
             paginator="true" 
             rows="10">
    <f:facet name="header">  
        Base   
    </f:facet>
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/> 
    <p:column headerText="id">  
        <h:outputText value="#{acq.rowNum}"/>  
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="network code">  
        <h:outputText value="#{acq.networkCode}" />  
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

```
public class ReportBean implements Serializable {

 private TmpDataModel dataModel;
 private List<Report> list;
 private Report[] selected;

public ReportBean() {
    list = new ArrayList<Report>();
    // db 
    list.addAll(ReportHelper.getAll());
    dataModel = new TmpDataModel(list);
}


public class TmpDataModel extends ListDataModel<Report> implements SelectableDataModel<Report> {

public TmpDataModel() {
}

public TmpDataModel(List<Report> data) {
    super(data);
}

@Override
public Object getRowKey(Report t) {
    return t.getRowNum();
}

@Override
public Report getRowData(String rowKey) {   
    List<Report> cars = (List<Report>) getWrappedData();
    for (Report r : cars) {
        if (String.valueOf(r.getRowNum()).equals(rowKey)) {
            return for1;
        }
    }
    return null;
  }
 }





<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<f:view>
    <h:head>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="resources/js/adm_js.js" />
        <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head"/>
        <ui:insert name="head"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/adm_css.css"/>
        <ui:insert name="content"/>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

p.s: I tested the app with  IE9 and its working faster but I still don’t understand why and how ShowCase example is working with IE8

any advice will be very helpfully

Thanks

Comment: How many records/cells? IE is known to have an extremely poor HTML `<table>` rendering engine. If more than 100 records, consider filtering/pagination like Google does.

Comment: 2000 records i also add pagination option to the table but still its very slow

Comment: There's the cause. The whole approach is simply inefficient. As to pagination, note that it should take place fully server side and not client side and that you should really have only 10 records at the same time in the bean and not all 2000 in a view/session scoped one. PrimeFaces has a `LazyDataModel` which solves this all.

Comment: thanks i will try to use the server side